# Insert JSON into Mongocxx

Tags: c++, json, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm currently trying to insert a JSON file into my mongoDB. I've already seen that this was solved by making use of the mongo::BSONObj in the past... But this doesnt seem to be an option since they released the new mongocxx driver for c++11. This is what I found in the bsoncxx src files:

```
BSONCXX_API document::value BSONCXX_CALL from_json(stdx::string_view json);
/// Constructs a new document::value from the provided JSON text
///
/// @param 'json'
///  A string_view into a JSON document
///
/// @returns A document::value if conversion worked.
///
/// @throws bsoncxx::exception with error details if the conversion failed.
///
```

How do I get my JSON file into a `stdx::string_view`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `bsoncxx::stdx::string_view` can be constructed from a `std::string`. Simply load your file contents (assuming it contains a single JSON object) into a `std::string` (perhaps via `std::ifstream`), and pass that `std::string` to `bsoncxx::from_json`. The object returned from `bsoncxx::from_json` is a `bsoncxx::document::value`, which is a resource-owning type that contains a BSON document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worked well! is there a way to load in more than just one Object (e.g. arrays and stuff) at a time?

Comment: The enclosing entity must be an Object, but it can certainly contain nested Arrays and other Object, etc. If you are looking to load multiple JSON documents stored sequentially in a text file into something like a `std::vector` of `bsoncxx::document::value`, then no, we don't have something like that, but it would be straightforward to implement yourself.

Comment: Do `bsoncxx::document::value bsonObj = bsoncxx::from_json(your_json_string);`